# Qiskit spends a lot of time on method acquire of thread.lock objects

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am trying to run VQE algorithm with Qiskit, using the following code:

```
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

def optimize_angles_ma_qiskit(graph: Graph, p: int) -> float:
    estimator = Estimator()
    ansatz = get_ma_ansatz(graph, p)  # composes some parameterized QuantumCircuit
    optimizer = optimize.minimize
    initial_point = np.ones((ansatz.num_parameters,)) * np.pi / 8
    vqe = VQE(estimator, ansatz, optimizer, initial_point=initial_point)
    maxcut_hamiltonian = get_observable_maxcut(graph)  # returns SparsePauliOp representing target Hamiltonian
    result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(-maxcut_hamiltonian)
    return -result.eigenvalue.real
```

The code was taking surprisingly long time to run, so I profiled it with `cProfile`, and I saw that >80% of running time is spent on `~:0(<method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects>)`, which seems to originate from within qiskit (I do not have any parallelization on my side of the code). Does anyone know if there is a setting to turn off internal parallelization or anything else I could do to make it spend less time on this?
[image: profiler result]